# How to prove that convolution is associative and distributive with "plus"

Tags: calculus, integration

The convolution is defined as:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x-t)g(t)dt=f*g(x)$$
I want to prove the associativity and distributivity of it:$$f*(g*h)=(f*g)*h$$
$$f*(g+h)=f*g+f*h$$

I expand them but I find that it seems difficult to process especially how to change the order of integration.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:
For the first try writing out the integral then using a simple substitution like $u=x-t$

The second one follows from the fact that the integral is a linear operator. So,
\begin{align*}
f*(g+h) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-t)(g(t)+h(t))\,dt\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-t) g(t) \, dt +\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x-t)h(t) \,dt
\end{align*}